# Bluetooth locating with RSSI and only one receiver

Tags: signal-analysis

Is there a method to find the relative direction of a Bluetooth device to the receiver?

A quick Google search on "Bluetooth positioning" returns several methods using triangulation, but I don't want to use multiple receivers. Also, I don't need to know the distance, only the relative angle to the receiver is enough.

Comment: What information should a single receiver use to determine the direction?

Comment: @MattL.: With the equipments I have, only RSSI (signal strength - scalar) is available for the receiver.

Comment: OK, but I'd say that there can't be a way to determine direction from signal strength. Do you think otherwise?

Comment: @MattL.: My current solution is using 1 receiver but place it at different locations & record the results, i.e. simulating multiple receivers using 1. But I wonder if there's a more clever (maybe at the cost of computation resource/time) method.

Edit: Using multiple receivers we can triangulate the position (therefore get the direction) of the lost device with only signal strength.

Comment: I know about triangulation, but the whole point is that you get several RSSI values (one per receiver) from which - given the geometry - a crude estimate of the position can be computed. With only one receiver there's only 1 RSSI value. I don't see how you could even theoretically say anything about location (other than distance) in that case.

Comment: This topic may be more appropriate for: http://ham.stackexchange.com/ or http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

If the environment does not contain a lot of 2.4 GHz radio reflecting objects, you can try shielding one side of the BTLE receiver's antenna (it might be tiny) with a large conductive object, the rotating the shield and antenna configuration.   The difference between RSSI's will be greatest when the shield is between the source and receiver antenna compared to the opposite orientation.